# SSL redirect and AAM not working on a Workflow which is using the original/install URL

Tags: workflow, tasks, alternate-access-mapping, ssl

A year ago, I created our SharePoint site under a test name.  I then added an AAM to extend it to our production name.  Just a month ago, I added an SSL redirect in IIS which sends all http requests to https.  Everything works great.   Discovered last week that when a user creates a workflow, the URLs of the tasks is http (instead of https) and has the test name rather than the production name.

Anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks much!

Comment: how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is normal as the AAM doesn't know about your redirect, therefore the Workflow engine is not able to populate the proper Url. You should either use a Reverse'Proxy (e.g. ForeFront TMG, ISA 2006 ) that could automatically change your HTTP to HTTPS or Extend the Web Application to use HTTPS too.

Besides you can make also enable the "Configure Cross-Firewall Access Zone" to specify which of the URLs should be considered for the external alerts, emails and mobile urls.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Months ago, I had extended the web application to use HTTPS and it is working.  I did some further testing this morning with the URLs and discovered that the install/original URL of http://tempname.abc.com does not work at all (just prompts me repeatedly to login & then reports "401 Unauthorized".  Which would be fine except that as you pointed out that's also where the Workflow is trying to go.  Both of my http and https AAMs https://prodname.abc.com and http://prodname.abc.com work fine.  How do I get the Workflow to redirect too?  Thanks!

Comment: Usually that is created in your AAM under Edit Public URLS. You need to put a link the Internet URL and also use the new configuration settings for "Cross-Firewall Access Zone". Usually the Workflows get this automatically, e.g .Approval workflow uses it in the TaskProcess: Item URL (UAG) as the property.

Comment: Thanks.  I have both in place as you've suggested and the original URL still does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry, i got lost in the middle - so which configuration is now in place?? The IIS rewrite would NOT fix it, where as the Extended Web App will most likely do!

Comment: Apologies for my confusion.  Hopefully this will help clarify - I have setup 2 AAMs for http://tempname.abc.com - one is http://prodname.abc.com (Internet) and the other is https://prodname.abc.com (Extranet).  I have Extended the original Web App of http://tempname.abc.com (which has http & https setup on it) to http://prodname.abc.com (only http as when I add https it stops working).  Lastly I have an URL rewrite on http://prodname.abc.com to SSL.  Do I also need to Extend http://tempname.abc.com to https://prodname.abc.com?  Thank you!

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the 'http/https' portion of my URLs to stay in my post which makes it difficult to follow.  My apologies for that.

Comment: If I Extend the original web app to include https will that affect the https AAM that I already have in place.  i.e. Will they conflict?

Comment: Nope, they should be updated simply.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the UpdateAlert in powershell.
Here is a link on the explanation http://www.wssdemo.com/Lists/stsadm/DispForm.aspx?ID=189&ContentTypeId=0x01001F9A291A8D9053488BAC958E9E294593